# Speedtest python script

Tags: python

Hello there i'm new to python and I'm trying to do speed testing using python getting data from (speedtest.net). I have been looking through git hub and found the speedtest-cli. But it has a lot of features I don't need. I just want to make a simple script that will run 3 times. I found some API but I'm not sure how to modify it to loop three times. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import speedtest

servers = []
# If you want to test against a specific server
# servers = [1234]
x=0
for x in range(0, 2):
    s = speedtest.Speedtest()
    s.get_servers(servers)
    s.get_best_server()
    s.download()
    s.upload()
    s.results.share()
    results_dict = s.results.dict()
```

Comment: Try `for x in range(0,3)`

Comment: or just `for x in range(3)`. `range(start, end, step)` - `start` inclusively and `end` exclusively. check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

Comment: I have already tried that, the problem is that it doesnt loop at all. It outputs the result once and thats it.

Comment: we can't help if we don't know what is going on... in your question you only said `make a simple script that will run 3 times`. At least show us what kind of error you've got if range is not real problem

Comment: sorry, I essentially want to get the script to run the speed test three times. So it'll run the test in 3 different instances right after another so it'd output something like. download 10mbs upload 5mbs and then run the test again and have download 8mbs upload 6mbs and one last time.

Comment: @aiven im not getting errors right now, the script is just not looping. It runs the test once. I want it to run 3 times lol

Comment: I think the issue is that you are looking at the `results_dict` value which gets reset in each loop. You have to either add the result to a variable outside the for loop scope or print off the results each loop like @Aiven answer below.

Comment: anyone know how to write into a txt/csv file. I've looked at tutorials but it didnt work . Heres what I have.

Answer (score 14):

```
import speedtest


def test():
    s = speedtest.Speedtest()
    s.get_servers()
    s.get_best_server()
    s.download()
    s.upload()
    res = s.results.dict()
    return res["download"], res["upload"], res["ping"]


def main():
    # write to csv
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('download,upload,ping\n')
        for i in range(3):
            print('Making test #{}'.format(i+1))
            d, u, p = test()
            f.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(d, u, p))
    # pretty write to txt file
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(3):
            print('Making test #{}'.format(i+1))
            d, u, p = test()
            f.write('Test #{}\n'.format(i+1))
            f.write('Download: {:.2f} Kb/s\n'.format(d / 1024))
            f.write('Upload: {:.2f} Kb/s\n'.format(u / 1024))
            f.write('Ping: {}\n'.format(p))
    # simply print in needed format if you want to use pipe-style: python script.py > file
    for i in range(3):
        d, u, p = test()
        print('Test #{}\n'.format(i+1))
        print('Download: {:.2f} Kb/s\n'.format(d / 1024))
        print('Upload: {:.2f} Kb/s\n'.format(u / 1024))
        print('Ping: {}\n'.format(p))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ok now it works, but it's giving me a lot of extra info. I just wanted the download, upload, and ping lol. How can I fix that.

Comment: just pick needed info from `results_dict`: `results_dict['download']`

Comment: holy cow dude, thanks. How did you know what to print? instead of all the  extra stuff.

Comment: how can I turn it into a txt/csv file i tried using open() and write etc but none worked

Comment: holy molly @aiven, thank you so much that's brilliant. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 4):

we can use this way

```
import speedtest

def getNetSpeed():
    speedTestHelper = speedtest.Speedtest()
    
    speedTestHelper.get_best_server()

    #Check download speed 
    speedTestHelper.download()

    #Check upload speed
    speedTestHelper.upload()

    #generate shareable image
    speedTestHelper.results.share()

    #fetch result
    return speedTestHelper.results.dict()

for i in range(3):
   print(getNetSpeed())
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use the library much easier Pyspeedtest

```
import pyspeedtest
st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()
st.ping()
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyspeedtest/

Answer (score 2):

Hare Krishna

**Try, this is best way to fetch net speed. It works in both Android and Windows.**

```
import speedtest

st = speedtest.Speedtest() 
 
while True:  
    download_speed = st.download()
    
    print('Download Speed: {:5.2f} Mb'.format(download_speed/(1024*1024) ))
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31148868)